# jQuery change single element from class

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using jQuery to check if an element is on screen. I'm selecting the element by it's class since I have multiple elements that should do the same but at different moments. When one element is on screen I'm changing it (fadeIn + animated slide up).

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $(".material-slide-up").each(function(){
    if(isScrolledIntoView($(this))) {
      $(this).fadeIn(1000);
      $(this).addClass("slideInUp animated");
    }
  });
});
```

When I run the current code all the elements with the same class are changed. I think it's because I'm using "each".

Is there a way to only change one element from the same class that is on screen?

Comment: As suggestion, add the `else {}` part: `$(this).removeClass("slideInUp animated");` Your code doesn't contain errors as far I can see. If the external function `isScrolledIntoView($(this))` returns only the visible elements, and the class is removed otherwise, the you could pick e.g. the 3rd visible element by `$('.slideInUp animated').eq(2)` and do other things with it, and only with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little helper function like this is great

```
$.fn.inView = function(){
if(!this.length) return false;
var rect = this.get(0).getBoundingClientRect();

return (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight ||  document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
);

};
```

Now, you did not share your DOM, so we will use mine, here is the link to the pen, scroll down to see the effect.

The calling function should look like this

```
 $(window).on('scroll',function(){ 
 var imgs = $('img');
 imgs.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.inView() && $this.addClass('magictime vanishIn');
}) ;
});
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/zBLEXR

If you show your full code, I can adapt that for you, but this should be easy to figure out now.

Comment: try again, i was just cleaning up the code a bit.click on the arrow and then scroll down or just scroll down

Comment: Let me know if you can adapt it to your code and make it work, that pen runs a lazy load plugin as well.But should work without that too

Comment: Thanks, this works for what I've asked for. I just need to tweak it because right now it load when the full element is on page while I need to get it loaded when the top + 100 px is visible.